# Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un proyecto que consiste en usar una base de datos de MySQL con una interfaz grafica de C#, el punto es que hay un item/elemento que consiste en agregar 2 fechas pero al compilar me arroja un error con los "DateTimePicker".

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
void BtnAgregarClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    String A,B,C,D,E;
    A = txtCodigo.Text;
    B = txtISBN.Text;
    C = txtBoleta.Text;
    D = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    E = dateTimePicker2.Text;
    if (A != "" && B != "" && C !=null && D != null && E != null){
        string query = "INSERT INTO prestamo VALUES("+"'" + A + "'," + "'" + B + "'," + "'" + C +"'," +  "'" + D + "'," + "'" + E + "')";
        MessageBox.Show(query);
        MainForm.Insert(query);
        txtBoleta.Clear();
        txtCodigo.Clear();
        dateTimePicker1.Value == DateTime.Today;
        dateTimePicker2.Value == DateTime.Today;
    }
    else 
        MessageBox.Show("Ingresa todos los datos");

}
```

Comment: Mi solución sería guardar primero el valor de las fechas en una variable y después asignarla y otra cosa porque no utilizas otra función para regresar el dia actual de la fecha y no un control.

Comment: Si de todos modos vas a ocupar una línea para asignar valores a A, B, C, D y E, ¿porqué no las declaras y asignas valores en la misma línea donde las asignas en vez de tener una línea extra de declaración? puedes ahorrarte la línea"String A,B,C,D,E;" puedes usar var, por ejemplo "var A = txtCodigo.Text;" o "string A = txtCodigo.Text;". Recuerda que hay veces que menos líneas crean código mas entendible y fácil de mantener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tu problema es que estás realizando una comparación en vez de una asignación en esta parte de tu código

```
dateTimePicker1.Value == DateTime.Today;  
dateTimePicker2.Value == DateTime.Today;
```

Usa el operador de asignación `=`  en vez del comparador `==`